# How to make sliding menu with tabs in Python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu

Please can any One tell me how a could make a tkinter Gui with sliding menu like thise this e image.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can create a frame that is shown each time the menu is pressed.

Comment: Keep in mind tkinter is not a modern gui toolkit and does not have anything inbuilt for hamburger menu.